# I am trying to implement ext js combobox with checkbox. This works fine when I select the item from list scrolling up and down

Tags: html, dom, extjs

I am trying to implement ext js combobox with checkbox (in 6.5.1 version). This works fine when I select the item from list scrolling up and down.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bqf&view/editor

Whenever I type for the item in the field and select the item in the list I don't see the item selected. Also clicking on the check box to select the item and clicking on the name to deselect the item the component behaves abnormally. Can someone please help me to correct this code

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem but I think there are better ways in ExtJS to achieve a multi selection like that. Check out [tagfield](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html) for example.

Comment: Ext tag field grows horizontally and vertically based on number of times selected. I don't want the component to grow based on number of items. The size of the component has to be same irrespective of number of items selected.

Comment: Still, this multiSelect option for combos is deprecated since version 5.1.0, and they offer either tagfield or multiselector: see documentation: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-multiSelect, and fixed width / height can be a problem if your user selects more items. It is generally not a good idea to fight the framework. Even if you find a workaround it could be broken when you upgrade the a newer version of ExtJS.